# writing a script in perl to convert all files in a folder to another format

Tags: perl, ascii

Question is 2 fold:

1. I'm writing a perl (not to experienced with perl) script and can get it to convert one file at a time from csv to ascii. I want to do a loop that takes all csv's in a folder and converts them to ascii/txt.
2. Is perl the best language to be attempting this with? I assumed yes since i can successfully do it one file at a time but having a very hard time figuring out a way to loop it.

I was trying to figure out how to load all the files into an array then run the loop for each one, but my googling has reached its limit and i'm out of ideas.
here's my working script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use open IN => ':encoding(UTF-16)';
use open OUT => ':encoding(ascii)';

my $buffer;

open(my $ifh, '<', 'Software_compname.csv');
read($ifh, $buffer, -s $ifh);
close($ifh);

open(my $ofh, '>', 'Software_compname.txt');
print($ofh $buffer);
close($ofh);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the following loop to your script and give it the files to process as arguments:

```
for my $input_file (glob shift) {
    (my $output_file = $input_file) =~ s/csv$/txt/ or do {
        warn "Invalid file name: $input_file\n";
        next;
    };

    my $buffer;

    open my $ifh, '<', $input_file;
    read $ifh, $buffer, -s $ifh;
    close $ifh;

    open my $ofh, '>', $output_file;
    print{$ofh} $buffer;
    close $ofh;
}
```

Comment: ok. Thanks choroba. How do I tell it what files to go process? This is where I hit the wall with trying to use an array.

Comment: Just run the script as `myscript.pl folder/*.csv`.

Comment: I took the script and put the pl file in the same folder as the csv's and I tried running it from command line and am getting can't open "folder/*.csv "no such file or directory error. I tried switching folder with the actual folder name and got the same error.

Comment: @Fosterocalypse: If you are in the folder with the files, just say `myscript.pl *.csv` or `myscript.pl ./*.csv`.

Comment: that got me a little further now its erroring out saying can't open *.csv  in the line 'open my $ifh, '<', $input_file;'

Comment: @Fosterocalypse: What OS are you running?

Comment: Windows 7 and once i iron it out i'm moving it to server 2003

Comment: @Fosterocalypse: OK, MSWin let the application do the globbing. Try it again with the updated code, please.

Comment: I did run it with the change in the code you made. Script executes but nothing happens. I feel like i'm missing the part that would actually feed it the file if that makes sense.

Comment: @Fosterocalypse: Run it as `myscript.pl *.csv`.

Comment: Awesome that did execute with an output I wanted when I added the argument "*.csv" like you said. The only weird thing is now it has in the txt file the information from the csv but also a line of japanese or chinese characters in between each line fro the csv. I know this is outisde of the question i originally posted but any ideas?

Comment: @Fosterocalypse: Can you share a sample of an input file?

Comment: ਍一漀搀攀Ⰰ䌀愀瀀琀椀漀渀ഀഀ
compname,DameWare Mini Remote Control
਍䐀䴀䄀圀匀䄀䴀䄀刀䜀䔀㄀㌀㌀㜀Ⰰ䰀甀愀 昀漀爀 嘀椀猀甀愀氀 匀琀甀搀椀漀ഀഀ
compname,Microsoft Press Training Kit Exam Prep Suite 70-515 Here is the first few lines to give you an idea. 
਍䐀䴀䄀圀匀䄀䴀䄀刀䜀䔀㄀㌀㌀㜀Ⰰ䴀椀挀爀漀猀漀昀琀 嘀椀猀甀愀氀 匀琀甀搀椀漀 ㈀　㄀　 匀攀爀瘀椀挀攀 倀愀挀欀 ㄀ഀഀ
compname,Microsoft Office 2007 Primary Interop Assemblies
਍䐀䴀䄀圀匀䄀䴀䄀刀䜀䔀㄀㌀㌀㜀Ⰰ䴀椀挀爀漀猀漀昀琀 伀昀昀椀挀攀 嘀椀猀甀愀氀 圀攀戀 䐀攀瘀攀氀漀瀀攀爀 ㈀　　㜀ഀഀ
compname,Microsoft Office Visual Web Developer MUI (English) 2007
਍䐀䴀䄀圀匀䄀䴀䄀刀䜀䔀㄀㌀㌀㜀Ⰰ䴀椀挀爀漀猀漀昀琀 伀昀昀椀挀攀 匀栀愀爀攀搀 匀攀琀甀瀀 䴀攀琀愀搀愀琀愀 䴀唀䤀 ⠀䔀渀最氀椀猀栀⤀ ㈀　　㜀ഀഀ
compname,Microsoft Office Shared MUI (English) 200

Comment: If there isn't anything I can do I can work around it. With your help I am able to complete the task I set out to accomplish but at this point its more for aesthetics and if I have to compile more advanced data reports out of my output reports.

Comment: @Fosterocalypse: The problem might be that `-s` returns the size in bytes, while `read` excepts the size in characters.

Comment: I will have to play with it to tweak it but you got me miles ahead of where I was at thanks again @choroba

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it from the Perl side only, I would suggest using [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/~rclamp/File-Find-Rule-0.33/lib/File/Find/Rule.pm):

```
use File::Find::Rule;
my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()
                            ->name('*.in')
                            ->in(my @input_directories = ('.'));
# etc.
```

regards,
matthias